# Verifying a RS256 signed JWT

Tags: python, jwt, rsa

I've tried using my public key vs. using the private key, putting a `b` in front, doing 3 vs. 1 quotes vs. one quote (and many more things I see here on Stackoverflow) and I keep getting the following error:

`ValueError: Could not deserialize key data`.

Any ideas?

```
import jwt

secret_key='''MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwE...pTeoOgWZ'''

token = '''eyJraWQiOiI4NkQ4OEtmIiwiNG2Bua1WoKEI8T..._cXnyThWA'''

#public_key = '''iGaLqP6y-SJCCBq5Hv6pGDbG_SQ11MNj...Mb0jcOTmBRZA2QuYw-zHLwQ'''

payload = jwt.decode(token, secret_key, algorithms=['RS256'])

return payload
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the complete public key including the begin and end delimiters and use `"""` or `'''` for a multiline string:

```
import jwt
token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.K71d-kndywmuxJR-SzDqTARcHJBsHezMeRtDwn4S0NMd3ZmW1LKKqoVQv8rMNam4HK6hsSmB0sqIpKfiLFn73HC1j9-fdBafZNy-9eL4cNr1ldwxj5jD6CwPMjT0mOB01liHFPiIfHDabYV2FzFEV8oaX8CxVL7_CLLv2I01NHo"

pubkey = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDCcbV4zk01saMn/VzIDN7rOY8D
BTYGnH6fnYB/wTKBHme6MpuOv+4d48ZKDseP8EcTFQmmAmKeKRGJUzSJ9cN2KlND
a4y2gkEsqh8a9U/7492hVWNB6JkSPrdqrkRho9/q9gCcDlTZROY/RDuf3Y1F1riV
tiFvXvfCp75fpLceIQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""


payload = jwt.decode(token, pubkey, algorithms=['RS256'])
print(payload)
```

Output:

> {'sub': '1234567890', 'name': 'John Doe', 'iat': 1516239022}

(no worries about the key, I just created it online just for demonstration purpose)

Comment: Thanks @jps. Can you say why adding the “——BEGIN PUBLIC...” part matters? I’ve seen many stackoverflow threads without it.

Comment: found something [here](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/issues/359#issuecomment-420093542)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My public key above wasn't actually a public key. It is a **RSA key modulus**. I had to use [this tutorial](https://baptistout.net/posts/convert-jwks-modulus-exponent-to-pem-or-ssh-public-key/) to take this RSA key modulus and the **exponent** to generate a public key. When i did this, then the `JWT.decode` functionality worked just fine.

Thanks @jps for your help!